# My google-fu is failing me, does anyone have a link to the following question

Tags: discussion

There was a question and answer from someone who actually worked on the SQL development team where they gave a long list of reasons why not to truncate an MSSQL Log file (it had something to do with index fragmentation).

Does anyone know what this question was? I've been searching for ages and I can't find it!

Comment: My guess is it was from Paul Randal.  He use to run the dev team for the storage engine.  I'll look and see if I can find it.  Have a look through Paul's blog, though.  Tons of good stuff there including why it's bad news to truncate a log file.  http://sqlskills.com/blogs/paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these what you're looking for?  They're Paul Randal's posts that include 'truncate'.

https://serverfault.com/search?q=truncate+user:1992

Comment: Got it - it was http://serverfault.com/questions/12793/how-do-i-reduce-transaction-log-backup-size-after-a-full-backup/13088#13088 - thanks